# What causes Dokan Stripe Connection HTTP error 500?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, stripe-payments

I was working on a WordPress site that uses Dokan Multi-vendor Plugin to utilise its e-commerce functions. It also uses Stripe Connect as a payment gateway so each seller gets a commission from each sale. For each seller to receive payment, each seller account has to connect to their own Stripe account (as illustrated here: https://wedevs.com/docs/dokan/modules/how-to-install-and-configure-dokan-stripe-connect/)

This function has been around for a while on the site and had been working perfectly fine. However, this afternoon when I clicked "Connect to Stripe" blue button (as shown in the link above), I get an "HTTP error 500" from Chrome. Now all of the users cannot connect to Stripe Connect.

I figured this might have something to do with SSL, but I did not change any of the Cert or Key, or their configuration.

I am running Apache server with Ubuntu 16.04

Here is the conf file:

`<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/mywebsite.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/blablabla.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

```
ServerName mywebsitel.com
ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/public_html

LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/logs/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/mywebsite.com/logs/access.log combined
```

Error log showed two errors:

`[Mon Oct 15 17:27:35.146054 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 22095] [client 2600:c02:1020:4202::ac10:826a:52934] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation
[Mon Oct 15 17:29:33.168787 2018] [ssl:error] [pid 21905] [client 64.41.200.106:48000] AH02042: rejecting client initiated renegotiation`

Anyone had any idea? This is a critical component to the site and this problem just suddenly occurred!

Comment: I have replaced the URL with "mywebsite.com" for security reasons.

Comment: Also, after fiddling with my files, I can solve this problem by changing the SSL certs and private permission to 777 instead of 700, but obviously this is a very dangerous way to go. Any advice?